# Can I install Outlook App in my Hotmail (Outlook) email Account

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365, office-2013, office365-apps

Actually i am newer in Develop Office 2013 App.

Can I install Outlook 2013 App in my Hotmail (outlook) email account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### No, you can't, you not install in your normal email account.

You must have to Office365 account. If not you [create Office365](http://office365support.ca/signing-up-for-the-new-office-365-2/) trial/paid account.

Then after you install App in `Outlook web app` or `Outlook 2013` Application.